# Bootstrap, scale image with other content to fit in static row on a display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vbuf0gwL/62/

Basically dealing with three rows

```css
    img {
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height:100%;
    }
   
        html,
        body {
          height: 100%;
          overflow: hidden;
        }
        
        .modal-lg {
          max-width: 80% !important;
        }
        
        .my-container {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          height: 100%;
        }
        
        .my-container>.top [class^="col-"],
        .my-container>.bottom [class^="col-"] {
          background-color: #929292;
          color: white;
          text-align: center;
        }
        
        .my-container>.middle {
          flex-grow: 1;
          padding: 30px;
          background-size: cover;
        }
        
        .my-container>.middle>* {}
        
        #clock {
          /*background-color:#333;*/
          font-family: sans-serif;
          font-size: 40px;
          text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
          color: #fff;
        }
        
        #clock span {
          color: #fff;
          font-size: 40px;
          position: relative;
        }
        
        #date {
          margin-top: -10px;
          letter-spacing: 3px;
          font-size: 20px;
          font-family: arial, sans-serif;
          color: #fff;
        }
        
        .buttonContainer {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: center;
        }
```

```html
 <html>

    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link href="https://rawgit.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/master/build/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link href="src/ytv.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
      <script src="https://rawgit.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/master/build/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.4.0/jquery.marquee.min.js'></script>


    </head>

    <body>

      <div class="container-fluid my-container">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
      </div>

    </div>
        <div class="row middle">
          <div class="col-lg-6 leftFifty" id="leftFifty">
            <div class="leftContent" style="background-color: white; height: 100%; border: dotted 1px black;">

              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1024x942" />
              
              <!-- This is the div that is clicked in to select an image -->
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 rightFifty" id="rightFifty">
            <div class="rightContent" style="background-color: white; height: 100%; border: dotted 1px black; ">
              <!-- This is the div that is clicked in to select an image -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      
      </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

My problem is, I made a CMS where users can add images and text and when they save it it displays on large television displays.

I added max height and width of 100% to the images which is fine with just an image in one of the middle row columns, but with multiple images or an image with text, it pushes the image out of the container, past the footer row.

I want to make it so that when these are displayed, if the text spans more of the column then the images scale down so it fits in the column, since the middle row should always be between the header and footer with space between them.

This image shows what happens with just images and then what happens if text is added, but the third portion is what I want

[image]

How can I make this so that anything in the column will scale to always fit since this is a fixed static display with no interaction or scrolling?